# Change class property value based on passed parameter

Tags: c#

I have the class Car as shown.  Car has values assigned to the properties.  How can i change these values depending on a passed parameter when making a new instance of the class? (eg BMW, Volvo etc) In the constructor?

```
public class Car {
  public string Engine { get; set; } = "Engine1"; 
  public string Body { get; set; } = "Body1";
  public string Wheels { get; set; } = "Wheels1";
}
```

For example if i created the class: `Car car = new Car("BMW");`

Comment: with factory? Car class should not know brand value and it's eventual dependency to other properties ... also it doesn't make sens as brand should yet another property(in real life fx  many brands using the same engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you just need a constructor accepting a single parameter:

```
public class Car 
{
    public string Engine { get; set; } = "Engine1"; 
    public string Body { get; set; } = "Body1";
    public string Wheels { get; set; } = "Wheels1";
    public Car(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "BMW": 
                Engine = "BMW Engine";
                Body = "BMW Body";
                Wheels = "BMW Wheels";
                break;
            case "VW": ...
            case default: throw new ArgumentException("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch block in your constructor and assign the values to your properties. If an invalid argument is passed to your constructor, you could throw an exception:

```
public class Car {
  public string Engine { get; set; }
  public string Body { get; set; }
  public string Wheels { get; set; }

  public Car(string type)
  {
    switch(type)
    {
      case "BMW":
        Engine = "Engine1";
        Body = "Body1";
        Wheels = "Wheels1";
        break;
      case "Volvo":
        Engine = "Engine2";
        Body = "Body2";
        Wheels = "Wheels2";
        break;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid type!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should create a constructor
Car with parameters, in your example you should take a string parameter

```
Car(string Engine, string Body . . . )
{
//here in the constructor body, you should assign the value you took as 
//a parameter to you class internal field
//for example 
this.Engine = Engine;
}
```